# PFInstallation and adding a pointer to a PFUser

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, pfuser

I am trying to get to grips with Parse and build a simple chat app. For my **login** and **signup** code I have this snippet:

```
PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
        installation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
        [installation saveInBackground];
```

This code connects a PFInstallation to a PFUser so a push can be sent by querying a username.

When the app loads I first check to see if there is already a user logged in:

```
if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showFriends" sender:nil];
}
```

if a user is already logged in the show friends view controller is loaded. Do I need to set the installation again in this code to match the user? i.e.

```
  if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
        PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
        [installation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
        [installation saveInBackground];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showFriends" sender:nil];


}
```

Or is there no need because the user is already logged in? Am I right in thinking that the installation file is UNIQUE and only created once, matching the device to the push service so nothing really changes in that file unless I want to update the PFUser field I added?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if a user is already logged in the show friends view controller is loaded. Do I need to set the installation again in this code to match the user?

No. Installations and User classes act independently, but in your case since you set a relation then they can act together as well. Since you already set it in application `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` that device has uniquely identified its installation with the token you've provided (device token) so you don't have to call it again.
A User session is different. If you want the User to be logged in you will have to present the login VC somewhere, since it won't be there the first launch.

> Am I right in thinking that the installation file is UNIQUE and only created once, matching the device to the push service so nothing really changes in that file unless I want to update the PFUser field I added? thanks

Yes. That's pretty accurate. Just don't get confused. `PFUser currentUser` is not the same as `PFInstallation currentInstallation` anyone can sign on to a device but the app can only be installed once on a device making the installation unique. Not users.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no need to reset the PFUser to the instalation in if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showFriends" sender:nil];
} right?

Comment: Correct, once a relation is set it will always retain that state until you tell it otherwise